# enumerating subset minimal models with Python library clingo

Tags: clingo

I want to enumerate all subset minimal models. It works if I call clingo from the terminal but it fails when I use the clingo library for Python. What am I missing?

*example program*:

```
1 {x(C) : C=1..10} 2.
#show x/1.
```

*solutions from terminal*:

```
clingo program.asp --models=0 --enum-mode=domRec --heuristic=Domain --dom-mod=5,16
clingo version 5.4.0
Reading from program.asp
Solving...
Answer: 1
x(1)
Answer: 2
x(10)
...
Answer: 10
x(5)
SATISFIABLE

Models       : 10
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.001s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.001s
```

*solutions with Python and clingo*:

```
from clingo import Control, Model

control = Control(arguments=[f"--models=0", "--opt-mode=optN"])
control.heuristic = "domain"
control.dom_mod = "5,16"
control.enum_mode = "domRec"

control.add(name="base", parameters={}, program="1 {x(C) : C=1..10} 2.")
control.add(name="base", parameters={}, program="#show x/1.")

solutions = []

def add_solution_to_list(model: Model):
    solution = [symbol.arguments[0].number for symbol in model.symbols(shown=True)]
    solutions.append(solution)

control.ground(parts=[("base", [])])
result = control.solve(on_model=add_solution_to_list)
```

- `solutions` contains 55 elements:

  - `[[1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], ... , [9, 10], [8, 9]]`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add all the command options from the command line when you crate the `Control` object instead of setting by hand.

```
control = Control(arguments=[f"--models=0", "--opt-mode=optN", "--enum-mode=domRec", "--heuristic=Domain", "--dom-mod=5,16",])
```

If you want to sent them in a different way you would have to use the `Configurarion` API:

https://potassco.org/clingo/python-api/5.5/clingo/configuration.html